# React fetching timeout

Tags: reactjs, express, timeout, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a react app with express backend. When I make a post request from react, I can see the query being run in the database. however, when the query takes more than 2 minutes to run, React fetch process would stop, although the query would still keep running in the database and would return the result to express (I know it returned data to express because I had a console.log in the express code to show data length which did show up in the console after the query stopped running).

In the front end, it would show the following error. Anybody has any suggestions on how can run large query from React and get the data back without timeout? I have tried all the timeout settings, etc. thank you

POST http://localhost:4000/results net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
(anonymous) @ C:\Users...
1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: You have a request that takes longer than 2 minutes to execute? Why?

Comment: The query I am trying to run against snowflake database is sometimes complicated and it took snowflake that long to complete the query. I am building the desktop app so it is acceptable to have longer wait time. I think the frontend just thought there won't be any data coming back after 2 minutes. Is there any way I can make it to wait for longer than 2 minutes?